# CentOS Black Screen after 4+ hours of indexing

Tags: centos, virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine, liferay

I am running a CentOS virtual image on virtual box. It has liferay and solr installed on it and I am trying to index a Lar file that is 50+ MB of metadata. This is estimated to take more than 12 hours but before it can finish the virtual machine breaks and shows a black screen. My windows computer is doing fine and when I save the state of the virtual machine it loads back into the black screen state.

I believe that this is probably a load issue. My VM has 10 GB of ram and I have assigned 9GB to tomcats in the setenv file. I have also tried giving the VM 10GB of swap space which didn't help a bit.

How can I improve the performance of my machine to get this one time indexing to work or is there an actual way to fix this problem with CentOS itself? I am using Cent OS release 7.0.1406 (Core)

Answer (score 0):

If you believe it's just a load issue you may have to either configure `limits.conf` or put it in a cgroup and limit resources such that there's always a healthy amount of memory and cpu available at any given point in time. It will slow down the indexing (which would likely finish on its own eventually even with a blackout) but the VM should remain usable in the mean time.

I would also verify in the logs and sar reports that it actually is because the indexer is choking the system.